# CSS - target non text-shadow supporting browsers

Tags: css

Is there any CSS hack to target just browsers that do not support the `text-shadow` CSS property?

It is a very important visibility/readability/accessibility problem, since something like having light gray text with a dark shadow on a white bg may become unreadable if the dark text shadow is not visible. And the designer insists on using this, and not using text image replacements. (I could try and target recent browsers, but I had the surprise of even IE9 not understanding `text-shadow`, and god only knows what the support for this is on all the mobile devices out there...)

Comment: Your designer needs a serious accessibility crash course.

Comment: [Google text-shadow polyfill](http://www.google.com/search?q=text+shadow+polyfill) -> https://github.com/heygrady/textshadow

Comment: @BoltClock I know, but the design actually looks great and is easy to read with the text shadow rendered properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this script:

```
if (document.createElement('div').style.textShadow !== '') {
    document.documentElement.className += ' no-textshadow';
}
```

Then you can do:

```
.no-textshadow h1 {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was hoping for a CSS only solution to avoid loading a feature detection lib like Modernizr, but your solution is lightweight enough too...

Answer (score 1):

Not without JS, but there is a viable CSS-only substitute that I believe works for IE 6-9 and is valid. Heard of DXImage Transform?

Similar question + syntax example: [Is filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX="x", OffY="y", Color="color") a viable replacement for text-shadow: in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605755/is-filter-progiddximagetransform-microsoft-dropshadowoffx-x-offy-y-colo)

Comment: thanks, although I didn't want to bother to have a text shadow in IE, just to change the text color when the shadow is not supported to make the text readable... and I still need to actually to the testing for a few of the mobile browsers out there...